# Trying to subtract amount from column in database, showing amount on all accounts

Tags: php, mysql, database, html, phpmyadmin

**Objective:**

I am trying to subtract 0.05 from a column in my database on the push of an html button.

---

**What's going wrong:**

Everything is working fine, it is making the correct calculation and deleting the correct amount from my account, but it is displaying the new amount on every account in the database.

---

**Example:**

I have 10 in my account, and once i press the button, i now have 9.95 in my account. Unfortunately, now everyone has 9.95 in their accounts too!

---

**Code:**

*Html button and script for onclick:*

`<button id="playbutton" onclick="myAjax();location.href='5game.html'">Play (-5&#162;)</button>`

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function myAjax () {
$.ajax( { type : 'POST',
            data : { },
            url  : 'subtract5.php',              // <=== CALL THE PHP FUNCTION HERE.
            success: function ( data ) {
                alert( data );               // <=== VALUE RETURNED FROM FUNCTION.
            },
            error: function ( xhr ) {
                alert( "error" );
            }
        });
}
</script>
```

*PHP Code for subtracting 0.05 (file name: subtract5.php):*

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "my username"; <not actually this, just confidential
$password = "my password"; <not actually this, just confidential
$dbname = "accounts";
$cash_amount = $_SESSION['cash_amount'];

// Create connection

$userid = $_SESSION['id'];

// You must enter the user's id here. /\

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Fetch the existing value of the cash_amount against that particular user here. You can use the SELECT cash_amount from users where userid = $userid

$newAmount = $cash_amount - 0.05;

$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = $newAmount";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result)
{
   echo "Query Executed Successfully!";
}
else
{
   echo mysqli_error($conn);
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

---

**Prediction:**

I think this has something to do with the user id field, i wasn't sure what to put in it.

---

**Database layout:** 
Database: Accounts, 
Table: Users, 
Columns: id | first_name | last_name | email | password | cash_amount | hash | active

---

**Extra Question:**

On the main page of my website, it shows the cash amount. Once it has been changed it does not update until i log out and log back in again. Is there a thing i can put in the top php code like "session restart" to check for new amounts every time i open the page?

---

**Thanks:**

Thanks so much for helping, as you can see i'm kind of a noob at this :)

Comment: You can send user `id` with POST to your php script, and use it in `WHERE` clause in your query

Answer (score 1):

In the where clause of the query WHERE id = $userid:

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "my username"; <not actually this, just confidential
$password = "my password"; <not actually this, just confidential
$dbname = "accounts";
$cash_amount = $_SESSION['cash_amount'];

// Create connection

$userid = $_SESSION['id'];

// You must enter the user's id here. /\

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Fetch the existing value of the cash_amount against that particular user here. You can use the SELECT cash_amount from users where userid = $userid

$newAmount = $cash_amount - 0.05;

$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = $newAmount WHERE id = $userid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result)
{
   echo "Query Executed Successfully!";
}
else
{
   echo mysqli_error($conn);
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Now for some reason, it's not subtracting anything at all, just redirecting to the other page.

Comment: How do i check?

Comment: `$userid = $_SESSION['id']; echo $userid; die;`Check in console. And, Wait, How you get user id? @Patrick

Comment: Where can i find the console on mac, and what do you mean by your question?

Comment: *.. what do you mean by your question* Simple. When you are updating/subtracting some amount for user. So, for that particular user how you get user id? For Console:: Right Click, Inspect Element, go to console and check @Patrick. Have You Copied Code From Somewhere else?

Comment: ok i put in the command you told me to and it says, Unexpected identifier '$userid'  does that help?

Comment: Then, user id is not coming. Then, second question: How you get user id for that particular user? @Patrick

Comment: I'm getting the user id by contacting the database with $_SESSION['']; and putting the column name in the brackets.

Comment: Then, how you are not getting user id? do `echo $_SESSION['id']; die;` and check @Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the update to **only one user** using a WHERE clause

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = $newAmount WHERE user_id = $userid LIMIT 1";
```

The LIMIT is added for security.